# Sign test and z-test value

Tags: statistics

I am currently carrying out sign tests for a report I am putting together. I am using SPSS.

When I carry out the sign tests for large data sets (n = 52), SPSS calculates a Z-test value, however it does not for smaller data sets (n=17). Is it standard pratice to include the Z tests values in my report (in the style of a biological sciences journal), or just the p-values? If so, how do I calculate a Z-test value for the smaller data set?

NB the data is not normally distributed - perhaps I shouldn't be using the Z test value at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The $z$-Test is not an appropriate method for small data sets. You could try to use $t$-Test but to be honest, having a data set with $n=17$ samples should not be used for scientific conclusions.

Comment: It is possible, and preferable, to use the binomial distribution to do an exact 'sign test' when $n$ is small. It is easier to use a normal approximation to the binomial sign-test statistic.  When that is done there is a $Z$ statistic. // If your study is to be published, you should conform to the journal style for contents of summary tables. You could give sample sizes and p-values (not mentioning z-scores). Or you could give sample sizes, p-values, and z-values with `**`'s for missing z-values and a note explaining that these are for exact binomial tests.

Comment: Sometimes $n = 17$ would be quite enough to reach a conclusion in practice. Suppose you have pairs of patients matched for gender, age, severity of disease, etc. Then patients in each pair are randomized to standard surgical Procedure A or developmental  Proc B. If Proc B has worse outcomes in something like 16 of 17 matched pairs, I'd say Proc B is a lost cause. (That's something like p-value 0.0001 or 0.0002 soundly leading to rejection.)